# Computing Earley Parsing Steps

Tags: formal-grammars, compilers, parsers

I am trying to understand Earley parsing algorithm using an example. The grammar I use produces all the palindromes over $\Sigma=\{a,b,c\}$:

\begin{align*}
Z & \to S\\
S & \to a\,|\,b\,|\,c\,|\,aa\,|\,bb\,|\,cc\,|\,aSa\,|\,bSb\,|\,cSc
\end{align*}

For instance, the string `abcba` is derived as:
$$ Z\to S\to aSa\to abSba\to abcba $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I follow the algorithm steps, these are the Earley states I get:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|}
\hline S_{0}\\
\hline \begin{array}{ccc|c}
(1) & Z\to\bullet S & ,0 & \text{start rule}\\
(2) & S\to\bullet a & ,0 & \text{predict from (1)}\\
(3) & S\to\bullet b & ,0 & \text{predict from (1)}\\
(4) & S\to\bullet c & ,0 & \text{predict from (1)}\\
(5) & S\to\bullet aa & ,0 & \text{predict from (1)}\\
(6) & S\to\bullet bb & ,0 & \text{predict from (1)}\\
(7) & S\to\bullet cc & ,0 & \text{predict from (1)}\\
(8) & S\to\bullet aSa & ,0 & \text{predict from (1)}\\
(9) & S\to\bullet bSb & ,0 & \text{predict from (1)}\\
(10) & S\to\bullet cSc & ,0 & \text{predict from (1)}
\end{array}
\\\hline \end{array}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{|c|}
\hline S_{1}\\
\hline \begin{array}{ccc|c}
(1) & S\to a\bullet & ,0 & \text{scan from } S_{0}(1)\\
(2) & S\to a\bullet a & ,0 & \text{scan from } S_{0}(4)\\
(3) & S\to a\bullet Sa & ,0 & \text{scan from }S_{0}(7)\\
(4) & S\to\bullet a & ,1 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(5) & S\to\bullet b & ,1 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(6) & S\to\bullet c & ,1 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(7) & S\to\bullet aa & ,1 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(8) & S\to\bullet bb & ,1 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(9) & S\to\bullet cc & ,1 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(10) & S\to\bullet aSa & ,1 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(11) & S\to\bullet bSb & ,1 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(12) & S\to\bullet cSc & ,1 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(13) & Z\to S\bullet & ,0 & \text{complete from (1) and }S_{0}(1)
\end{array}
\\\hline \end{array}
$$

$$\begin{array}{|c|}
\hline S_{2}\\
\hline \begin{array}{ccc|c}
(1) & S\to b\bullet & ,1 & \text{scan from } S_{1}(5)\\
(2) & S\to b\bullet b & ,1 & \text{scan from } S_{1}(8)\\
(3) & S\to b\bullet Sb & ,1 & \text{scan from } S_{1}(11)\\
(4) & S\to\bullet a & ,2 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(5) & S\to\bullet b & ,2 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(6) & S\to\bullet c & ,2 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(7) & S\to\bullet aa & ,2 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(8) & S\to\bullet bb & ,2 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(9) & S\to\bullet cc & ,2 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(10) & S\to\bullet aSa & ,2 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(11) & S\to\bullet bSb & ,2 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(12) & S\to\bullet cSc & ,2 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(13) & S\to aS\bullet a & ,0 & \text{complete from (1) and }S_{1}(3)
\end{array}
\\\hline \end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{|c|}
\hline S_{3}\\
\hline \begin{array}{ccc|c}
(1) & \boldsymbol{S\to c\bullet} & ,2 & \text{scan from } S_{2}(6)\\
(2) & S\to c\bullet c & ,2 & \text{scan from } S_{2}(9)\\
(3) & S\to c\bullet Sc & ,2 & \text{scan from } S_{2}(12)\\
(4) & S\to\bullet a & ,3 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(5) & S\to\bullet b & ,3 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(6) & S\to\bullet c & ,3 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(7) & S\to\bullet aa & ,3 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(8) & S\to\bullet bb & ,3 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(9) & S\to\bullet cc & ,3 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(10) & S\to\bullet aSa & ,3 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(11) & S\to\bullet bSb & ,3 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(12) & S\to\bullet cSc & ,3 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(13) & S\to bS\bullet b & ,1 & \text{complete from (1) and } S_{2}(3)
\end{array}
\\\hline \end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{|c|}
\hline S_{4}\\
\hline \begin{array}{ccc|c}
(1) & S\to b\bullet & ,3 & \text{scan from } S_{3}(5)\\
(2) & S\to b\bullet b & ,3 & \text{scan from }S_{3}(8)\\
(3) & S\to b\bullet Sb & ,3 & \text{scan from } S_{3}(11)\\
(4) & \boldsymbol{S\to bSb\bullet} & ,1 & \text{scan from } S_{3}(13)\\
(5) & S\to\bullet a & ,4 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(6) & S\to\bullet b & ,4 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(7) & S\to\bullet c & ,4 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(8) & S\to\bullet aa & ,4 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(9) & S\to\bullet bb & ,4 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(10) & S\to\bullet cc & ,4 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(11) & S\to\bullet aSa & ,4 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(12) & S\to\bullet bSb & ,4 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(13) & S\to\bullet cSc & ,4 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(14) & S\to cS\bullet c & ,2 & \text{complete from (1) and } S_{3}(3)\\
(15) & S\to a S\bullet a & ,0 & \text{complete from (4) and } S_{1}(3)
\end{array}
\\\hline \end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{|c|}
\hline S_{5}\\
\hline \begin{array}{ccc|c}
(1) & S\to a\bullet & ,4 & \text{scan from } S_{4}(4)\\
(2) & S\to a\bullet a & ,4 & \text{scan from } S_{4}(7)\\
(3) & S\to a\bullet Sa & ,4 & \text{scan from } S_{4}(10)\\
(4) & S\to aSa\bullet & ,0 & \text{scan from } S_{4}(15)\\
(5) & S\to\bullet a & ,5 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(6) & S\to\bullet b & ,5 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(7) & S\to\bullet c & ,5 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(8) & S\to\bullet aa & ,5 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(9) & S\to\bullet bb & ,5 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(10) & S\to\bullet cc & ,5 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(11) & S\to\bullet aSa & ,5 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(12) & S\to\bullet bSb & ,5 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(13) & S\to\bullet cSc & ,5 & \text{predict from (3)}\\
(14) & S\to bS\bullet b & ,3 & \text{complete from (1) and } S_{4}(3)\\
(15) & S\to aS\bullet a & ,0 & \text{complete from (1) and } S_{4}(15)\\
(16) & Z\to S\bullet & ,0 & \text{complete from (4) and } S_{0}(1)
\end{array}
\\\hline \end{array}$$

Since $S_5$ contains $Z\to S\bullet$ we conclude that `abcba` was successfully derived.